# viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear with tab bar controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm looking into the viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear methods to better understand what they both do and I came across an [article](http://stablekernel.com/blog/uiviewcontroller-best-practices-viewwillappear-or-viewdidload/) which uses the example of a banking application to explain how these methods work:

> Consider a banking application that shows your current balance. A user
>   can tap on a button, which presents a list of nearby ATMs in a modal
>   view controller. In order to get the list of nearby ATMs, the
>   application must make a core location and web service request.
>
> In this situation, a programmer could get away with requesting the
>   list of nearby ATMs from the server in viewDidLoad. The view
>   controller is only presented once, both viewDidLoad and
>   viewWillAppear: will be called back to back and only once for that
>   particular view controller instance. The net effect of the code in
>   either of these two methods will be the same.
>
> But this is a bad idea. Consider what would happen if you wanted to
>   move the ATM view controller into a tab bar controller. Now, the ATM
>   view controller – with its ATM fetching code in viewDidLoad only
>   fetches the list of ATMs once. So you are in Atlanta on Tuesday, open
>   up your application to look for an ATM, then check your balance. Then
>   you travel to New York on Wednesday, re-open the banking application,
>   and you only see ATMs in Atlanta. The view was already loaded, no need
>   to call viewDidLoad and now you’re looking at stale data.

Sadly, I still don't fully understand how/why both viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear will be called 'back to back', or what adding the ATM view controller to a tab bar controller means in terms of these methods.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`viewDidLoad` method will call only once a life time of viewController and that is when viewController object will first load in memory.
where as `viewWillAppear` method will call every time when a view will appear to screen or you can say will be topViewController...

**Explanation**: 
Consider you have tab based app with two tabs. `Tab1` associated with `viewController1` and `tab2` is associated with `viewController2`. Now when you will run your app and you will see tab one is selected and `viewController1` is on view and you want to change to `tab2`, when you will tap on tab2 then `tabVieController2`'s object will create  and load to memory first time hence its `viewDidLoad` method will call, and soon after that it will appear to window and  `viewWillAppear` will also get call.
Now if you you try changing tabs by click on them only `viewWillAppear` methods will get called for both, as they are in memory already.

Comment: On initial startup that first view controller will be created and set to tabViewController selected viewController so its visible.... by default first tab is selected you can alter the behaviour

Comment: Thanks C_X. Where does this happen: '... and set to tabViewController selected viewController so its visible...'?

Comment: if you are using storyboard you can set one from there, other wise you can create a tabbarViewController and feed it viewControllers which will be tabs and then you can select one as selected...

Comment: ah ok I thought you might have meant something else! Thanks, I am accepting your answer as you made it clear to me that memory is intrinsic to understanding what goes on with these methods and while that might be obvious it wasn't to me! I really liked the other answer too from rckoenes which was very well composed but yours edged it, especially with the additional notes.

Answer (score 12):

It simple, [`viewDidLoad`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/title) get called when the view is load in, either via `NIB`, storyboard or with the [`loadView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/loadView) method. The [`viewWillAppear:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillAppear:) is called when the view is presented.

When a view is added to a tab bar it only gets load once, thus the [`viewDidLoad`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/title) will only be called once. But if the user switch to an other tab and back to the same view the  [`viewDidLoad`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/title) will not be called. This is because the view is already loaded.

However the [`viewWillAppear:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillAppear:)  is called in both cases just before the view is shown. Thus this will be called when the user first opens the tab and when it switches back to that tab.

Comment: This was a great help to me, I appreciate it rckoenes and it reinforced the other answer for me - both were very close in usefulness but I had to choose and other one just had a slight edge over yours for me personally. Wish I could accept two answers.

Answer (score 1):

I think they are referring to the fact that the view is loaded every time the modal view controller appears (thus the data is constantly refreshed) but only once when it is part of tab bar (only loaded on app launch). Kind of a whacky example to explain the methods though.

You might want to read up on the view controller lifecycle to know when to implement what in which method:

[Responding to Display-Related Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDisplay-Notifications/RespondingtoDisplay-Notifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH12-SW1)

[View Loading and Unloading](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html)